# Cant start docker-compose & failes on No module

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip, redhat

We installed the docker and docker-compose on our Linux red-hat 7.2

instructions - from the link - https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/scratchpads2/wiki/Install-Docker-and-Docker-Compose-(Centos-7)

Docker is running fine

But on docker-compose we get the following ( we installed it by  `pip install docker-compose` )

```
docker-compose --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from ..bundle import get_image_digests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/bundle.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .config.serialize import denormalize_config
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .config import ConfigurationError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/config.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .validation import match_named_volumes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/compose/config/validation.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jsonschema import Draft4Validator
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import importlib_metadata as metadata
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ._compat import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/_compat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from backports.configparser import ConfigParser
ImportError: No module named configparser
```

we try many steps in order to solve the issue about docker-compose  failed on `No module` , but without success ( each time its failed on other missing module ) 
any idea how to continue from this stage?

```
pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)



[root@server_mangmnt01]# pip show docker-compose
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Name: docker-compose
Version: 1.25.0
Summary: Multi-container orchestration for Docker
Home-page: https://www.docker.com/
Author: Docker, Inc.
Author-email: None
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: PyYAML, backports.ssl-match-hostname, texttable, enum34, ipaddress, subprocess32, jsonschema, dockerpty, websocket-client, docker, cached-property, backports.shutil-get-terminal-size, docopt, six, requests
Required-by:



[root@server_mangmnt01]# pip show docker
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Name: docker
Version: 4.1.0
Summary: A Python library for the Docker Engine API.
Home-page: https://github.com/docker/docker-py
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: Apache License 2.0
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: six, ipaddress, backports.ssl-match-hostname, requests, websocket-client
Required-by: docker-compose
```

Comment: can you try installing as indicated here --> https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Comment: the instructions is put the docker-compose under /usr/local/bin ( curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ) and then I see link to /usr/bin/...   , but why when we use pip install docker-compose , we get many issues about the modules ?  ( its more elegant to install it by pip insted to locate the docker-compose under folder )

Comment: seems to be a bug related to `backports`, also not to mention you're using `Python 2.7`, in any case this seems like a related bug --> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1812589

Comment: so , can we get fix for this bug ?

Comment: try following the instructions for downloading `docker-compose` from source, otherwise read that thread and see how those people solved their instance of the bug, not sure why you are asking me to fix this bug as if I maintain the package or something

Comment: sorry I not asking you about the bug , I just ask if you know some fix for this bug , sorry again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203252/discussion-between-jessica-and-aws-apprentice).

Comment: I'm having the same on the rapsberry pi 4

Comment: I've managed to run start docker-compose with virtualenv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case : docker-compose didn`t support python2
But yum in CentOS not supported python3 - remember it !

For switch python version
I replaced in /usr/bin symbilic link on python form python2 to python3

P.S. In CentOs i use midnight commander (mc) see screenshot

[image]